# PowerShell Start-BitsTransfer downloading a part of the file

Tags: powershell, ssis, ssis-2012

I was trying to download a csv file from a website using `Start-BitsTransfer` PowerShell command.

PowerShell script:

```
Start-BitsTransfer 
http://website1.com/datasets/2e5f1270a4a648628a1bbb66cfbf8a71_0.csv 
C:\Mydownloadfolder\Codes_in_Eng_v3.csv
```

The download is successful but it is a partial download!!.
The actual file size is 8kb,but it only downloaded 4kb. How to resolve this problem ?

The .ps1 is being executed using SSIS process task.

Comment: What about the data? Is the data is also partial ? Did you check the data inside the csv?

Comment: the actual file contians 240 records.but the downloaded file contains 96 records only

Comment: Send us a sample of the csv. We need to understand that first. Have you tried invoke-webrequest on the same context?